# how to send json object in ajax to a php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a json object to a php page demo.php using an ajax request

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var data = 
    {'name':'Sam','ID':'1345'};
    var test = {}
    test["data"] = JSON.stringify(data);
    $("#btnsend").click(function() 
    {   
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/demo.php",
            dataType:'json',
            data:test,
            success: function(data) 
                {
               console.log('success');
                         }
            error: function()
            {
                console.log('failure');

            }
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

This is what I tried in jQuery,but it is not rendered on my php page.In php I tried the following:

```
<html>
       <?php

       $json = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true);
       echo var_dump($json);

       ?>

       <body>
       Hello World !!!
       </body>
       </html>
```

But it is printing a failure in console. Please help me with this.

Comment: Remove all the HTML from it, it tries to parse an invalid JSON, just encode and echo it (no vardump etc, be sure no notices are generated)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** My initial answer was wrong, the reason you get to the `error` function, is that you have specified:

```
dataType:'json',
```

So jQuery expects the output of your php script to be valid json. It is not, you are returning text / html so that is why your `success` function is never reached.

The way you have setup your php script (outputting html), you probably should just remove:

```
dataType:'json',
```

and then you will get to your success function.

By the way, nothing is rendered on your page until you do something (show...) the `data` variable in your `success` function:

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log('success');
    $('#some_element').html(data);    // to put the output in #some_element
}
```

And in your php script you should only send back / echo out what you want to display in your html element, so no `html` or `body` tags.